# Do the exact words محمد رسول الله (Muhammad is the messenger of God) appear in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, shahada

> Though the two phrases of the shahada are both present in the Quran, they are not found there side by side as in the shahada formula.  -- [Shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada), Wikipedia

I would like to identify precisely which Qur'an verses this refers to (and edit the Wikipedia page to reference the Qur'an directly).  The Wikipedia page lists [Qur'an 37:35](https://quran.com/37/35) and [Qur'an 47:19](https://quran.com/47/19) as having the exact Arabic "لا إله إلا الله" (there is no god but God).

**Question**: Do the exact words محمد رسول الله (Muhammad is the messenger of God) appear in the Qur'an?

I recognize that there's words to the effect of "Muhammad is the messenger of God" throughout the Qur'an, but I'm wondering if this exact phrasing occurs.

The Wikipedia reference given is the book *Daily Life in the Medieval Islamic World* by J. E. Lindsay, 2005 (which is at [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=6J0WnWABM34C&redir_esc=y)), which basically says what it says in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Yeah these words are mentioned in [Quran 48:29](http://tanzil.net/#48:29)

> **مُّحَمَّدٌ رَّسُولُ اللَّـهِ** ۚ وَالَّذِينَ مَعَهُ أَشِدَّاءُ عَلَى الْكُفَّارِ رُحَمَاءُ بَيْنَهُمْ ۖ تَرَاهُمْ رُكَّعًا سُجَّدًا
>   يَبْتَغُونَ فَضْلًا مِّنَ اللَّـهِ وَرِضْوَانًا ۖ سِيمَاهُمْ فِي
>   وُجُوهِهِم مِّنْ أَثَرِ السُّجُودِ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ مَثَلُهُمْ فِي
>   التَّوْرَاةِ ۚ وَمَثَلُهُمْ فِي الْإِنجِيلِ كَزَرْعٍ أَخْرَجَ شَطْأَهُ
>   فَآزَرَهُ فَاسْتَغْلَظَ فَاسْتَوَىٰ عَلَىٰ سُوقِهِ يُعْجِبُ
>   الزُّرَّاعَ لِيَغِيظَ بِهِمُ الْكُفَّارَ ۗ وَعَدَ اللَّـهُ الَّذِينَ
>   آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ مِنْهُم مَّغْفِرَةً وَأَجْرًا
>   عَظِيمًا ﴿٢٩
>
> **Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah;** and those with him are forceful against the disbelievers, merciful among themselves. You see
>   them bowing and prostrating [in prayer], seeking bounty from Allah and
>   [His] pleasure. Their mark is on their faces from the trace of
>   prostration. That is their description in the Torah. And their
>   description in the Gospel is as a plant which produces its offshoots
>   and strengthens them so they grow firm and stand upon their stalks,
>   delighting the sowers - so that Allah may enrage by them the
>   disbelievers. Allah has promised those who believe and do righteous
>   deeds among them forgiveness and a great reward.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best.